# How do I match over multiple lines in perl

Tags: perl

Lets say I have a netlist file formatted like so for each module:

```
module module_name1(in1, in2,
    in3, in4, in5,
    out1, out2, out3
    out4, out5);
```

There are many of these throughout the netlist. I want to be able to grab the module name and the list of ports. Here is what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
open (my $INFILE, $input_file) or die "$input_file cannot be opened.\n";

my $outfile = "verilog.port.txt";
open (my $OUTFILE, '>', $outfile) or die "\nUnable to create $outfile\n";

my ($module_name,$port_list);

while (<>) {
  if ($_ =~ /module (\w+)\((.+)\)/m) {
    $module_name = $1;
    $port_list = $2;
    print $OUTFILE "Module Name: $module_name Port list: $port_list\n"
  }
}
close $INFILE;

close $OUTFILE;
```

This will only work if the module is instantiated in only 1 line.
For example if :

```
module module_name2(in1, in2, out1, out2);
```

and I will get something like:

```
Module Name: module_name2 Port list: in1, in2, out1, out2
```

However if the module is created over multiple lines like in my first example, my reg expression cannot pick it up. So I was wondering if there is a way to match through multiple lines using perl.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading files line by line, you need to read them either by paragraph (chunks separated by a empty line) or the entire file if if there is no such separation; otherwise `$_` contains only one line and will not match.

Also, the `/m` flag is not what you are looking for (`/m` makes `^`/`$` match beginning/end of lines), you need `/s` which makes `.` include newlines (see: the [perlreref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#OPERATORS) documentation page, the [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) page is a bit confusing)

By paragraph, this one liner should do the trick:

```
$ perl -l -00 -ne 'if ( /module (\w+)\((.+)\)/s) { @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/,$2); print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(", ", @ports)}' <<'EOF'
> module module_name1(in1, in2,
>     in3, in4, in5,
>     out1, out2, out3,
>     out4, out5);
>
>
> module module_name2(in21, in22,
>     in23, in24, in25,
>     out21, out22, out23,
>     out24, out25);
> EOF
Module name: module_name1 Ports: in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, out1, out2, out3, out4, out5
Module name: module_name2 Ports: in21, in22, in23, in24, in25, out21, out22, out23, out24, out25
```

You can use `-MO=Deparse` to see the entire code:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -l -00 -ne 'if ( /module (\w+)\((.+)\)/s) { @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/,$2); print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(", ", @ports)}'
BEGIN { $/ = ""; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    if (/module (\w+)\((.+)\)/s) {
        @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/, $2, 0);
        print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(', ', @ports);
    }
}
```

If you don't have empty lines separating the modules, you will need to get the entire file at once (slurp)

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'while (/module (\w+)\((.+?)\);/sg) { @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/,$2); print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(", ", @ports)}' <<'EOF'
> module module_name1(in1, in2,
>     in3, in4, in5,
>     out1, out2, out3,
>     out4, out5);
> module module_name2(in21, in22,
>     in23, in24, in25,
>     out21, out22, out23,
>     out24, out25);
> EOF
Module name: module_name1 Ports: in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, out1, out2, out3, out4, out5
Module name: module_name2 Ports: in21, in22, in23, in24, in25, out21, out22, out23, out24, out25
```

Again, you can use `-MO=Deparse` to see what is happening:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -l -0777 -ne 'while (/module (\w+)\((.+?)\);/sg) { @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/,$2); print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(", ", @ports)}'
BEGIN { $/ = undef; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    while (/module (\w+)\((.+?)\);/gs) {
        @ports = split(/\s*,\s*/, $2, 0);
        print "Module name: $1 Ports: " . join(', ', @ports);
    }
}
```

The key element in these approaches is the [`-0`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-0*%5B_octal%2Fhexadecimal_%5D) flag which in the `-00` form sets `$/` to the empty string enabling paragraph mode, and in `-0777` form  sets `$/` to undef enabling slurp mode (reading the entire file) (see also: [$RS](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#IO%3a%3aHandle-%3einput_record_separator(-EXPR-)) in the perlvar manual.)

A important caveat: [`-l`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D) sets the `$\` variable to `$/` (which by default is "\n"), and in this case it has to used before `-0` in the command line if you want the output to be separated by new lines.

For a more elegant approach, you can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = read_file($ARGV[0]);

my %modules = $data =~ /module (\w+)\((.+?)\);/sg;

$modules{$_} = [split(/\s*,\s*/, $modules{$_})] for keys(%modules);

print Dumper(\%modules);
```

This would give you a data structure containing all the information needed - see https://ideone.com/BuuR8I for a live demo

Answer (score 0):

See following code snippet for one of many possible solutions

NOTE: OP is missing in posted data block `,` after `out3`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;          # debug flag

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/[ \n]+/ /g;

my @lines = split ';', $data;

say Dumper(\@lines) if $debug;

for (@lines) {
    next unless /module\s+(.*)?\((.*)\)/;
    say "Module: $1 -- Ports: $2";
}


__DATA__
module module_name1(in1, in2,
    in3, in4, in5,
    out1, out2, out3,
    out4, out5);


module module_name2(in21, in22,
    in23, in24, in25,
    out21, out22, out23,
    out24, out25);
```

Output

```
Module: module_name1 -- Ports: in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, out1, out2, out3, out4, out5
Module: module_name2 -- Ports: in21, in22, in23, in24, in25, out21, out22, out23, out24, out25
```

Comment: You are consistently posting unfocused code snippets with no explanations. The result is that you are communicating your point very ineffectively. Your answers would be much better if you identified the problem ("`$_` only contains one line at any given time, and `.` won't match line feeds without `/s` anyway"), and if you provided even the shortest of explanations ("You can solve this problem by reading in the whole file into the variable and removing the line feeds"). (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @ikegami -- I think that the code is self-explanatory: read whole file into variable, replace sequential spaces to one and replace one or more `\n` (linefeed)  to one space, then split into array of lines on `;`, then skip all lines which do not include pattern `module`, while looking if line matches pattern _catch_ module name and it's parameters (ports). I do understand that if OP (or other person) can not read perl code then they will not understand it without explanation. But I expect that when they see the output they should ask `How does it work?` and try to understand it.

Comment: Re "*I think that the code is self-explanatory*", The lackluster performance of your answers --more than half (16) of the last 30 are non-positive-- indicates I'm not alone in thinking they do not sufficiently explain the issue and the solution. Note that this isn't about code readability (though you do tend to include irrelevant noise). /// Re "*But I expect that when they see the output they should ask* How does it work?", Of course! I'm a big fan and showing over explaining. But it's good to give context.

Comment: @ikegami - I find that many OPs are not able to ask properly what the problem is. No input data provided, no expected output given. At this point some improvisation is required -- generate assumed input, process data, generate some useful output to demonstrate `how it can be done`. Yes, my coding might be `rusty` as I learned perl about 25 years ago and _some my coding aged to that time_. I always pickup some good style if I see that it easy to read. Some posters put one liners which require good understanding perl options -- but from question it is obvious that OP is not _their guy_.

Comment: I'm not here to debate whether there is a problem with your answers or not. There clearly is. Just giving some friendly advice for making your answers useful. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @PolarBear In short and with best intentions: I strongly suggest to carefully and thoughtfully read (and re-read) ikegami's well-meant and very articulate advice, and to ponder over it, and work on it. (Btw: their various advice helped me a lot in the past, and it keeps helping.) And I absolutely back up everything in their comments, btw. Again: this is meant to be friendly and supportive. (I didn't vote.)

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree that reading line-by-line is 'inappropriate' when perl has the `..` [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

Take the OP code and modify as such:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/module/ .. /\)/) {
        $module_name = $1 if /module\s+(\w+)/;
        my $done=/\)/;
        s/.*\(//; s/\).*//;s/,\s+/, /g;
        chomp;
        $port_list .= $_;
        print $OUTFILE "Module Name: $module_name Port list $port_list\n" if $done;
    }
}
```

In other words, from lines matching `/module/` to lines matching `/)/`, accumulate the port list.

Comment: nobody said it's inappropriate per se, but it's inappropriate in the context of matching over multiple lines.